# Shrinking open interval empty?

Tags: limits

Let **(a, b)** an open interval in $\Bbb R$.

If $\lim_{b\to a}$, then is the resulting interval empty?

So my intuition is that it is empty, but since **b 'approaches' a**, I'm not sure if ever **b** reaches **a**.

Here's why I think it's empty:
$$(a, b):=\{x | a<x<b\},$$
$$\lim_{b\to a}b=a,$$
so clearly,
$$\lim_{b\to a}(a, b)=\{x | a<x<a\}=\emptyset.$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes - although no particular interval "along the way" is empty, the "limit" of the intervals is the emptyset.

Another good example of this is to let $X_a=(a, \infty)$. Then each $X_a$ is infinite, but the limit of the $X_a$s is empty! Do you see why?

---

We should be careful here: it's worth giving a precise definition of "the limit of a set." The one that makes the most sense is $$x\in\lim_{a\rightarrow b}X_a\quad \iff\quad \exists\delta>0\forall a[0<\vert a-b\vert<\delta\implies x\in X_a],$$ that is, $x$ is in the limit of the $X_a$s (here $X_a=(a, b)$) iff $x$ "eventually stays in" the $X_a$s. (In your example you probably want to tweak this a bit: since you're looking at $a<b$, you only want the "left hand" limit.)

However, you need to be extremely careful with this definition! For example, it is **not** the case that (using this definition) the complement of the limit is the limit of the complements! For example, let $X_a=\emptyset$ if $a$ is rational, and $\mathbb{R}$ if $a$ is irrational. Then

- What is $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}X_a$?
- What is $\lim_{a\rightarrow 0}X_a^c$? (Here "$^c$" denotes the complement.)

What's going on here is that the sets are not changing *monotonically*: as $a\rightarrow 0$ points are entering $X_a$, then leaving $X_a$, then entering again, etc. In the example you give, everything is nicely monotonic: if $a\le a'<b$, then $(a, b)\supseteq (a', b)$. But in general, the limit of sets is not something which behaves intuitively.

---

Two more comments:

- Note that in your question - and in my answer - we've talked about sets indexed by *reals*. We can also talk about the limit of a *sequence* of sets, that is, sets indexed by *natural numbers*; or other ways of indexing sets.
- Thinking about "limits of sets" might make you think: hey, wait a second! Limits in calculus make sense because of the *geometry* (or *topology*) of the real line; if I want to talk about limits of sets, do I need to have a geometric picture of *sets* of real numbers? The answer is: yes, you probably should, and you *can*! See e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hypertopology.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, but the way I would put the question is, whether the set
$$
\cap_{b > a} (a, b)
$$
is empty.  And it is: whatever the number $c > a$, there exists a $b$ such that $a < b < c$, so that $c$ is not in $(a, b)$ for that particular $b$, hence is not in the above intersection.

Finally, $a$ is not in the above intersection because it is not contained in any of the intervals $(a, b)$.